# How can I add a property to a collection in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

How can I add a property to a collection, NOT DOCUMENT
mongoose.connection.useDb("Categories").createCollection(categoryName)

Comment: You need to understand the concepts of document and collection in MongoDB. A document contains multiple properties/fields, while a collection consists of multiple documents. There is no property in the collection.

Comment: I see, when I console log a collection im able to see properties so I thought I could just add a custom one 
`{
    name: 'testing',
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: {
      readOnly: false,
      uuid: new UUID('47c28570-dh8e-4678-b6f2-f4ec977b4644')
    },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_' }
  },`

Comment: Hmmm, I think this is the metadata of the collection. But need to know the real reason why you try to achieve this.

Comment: The available options when creating a collection are documented here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/create/#create